Problema al monstrar estilos css y js en Angular
estoy intentando hacer una plantilla en angular, pero no se muestran los estilos ni el js correctamente.
Creo que todo esta correcto en el archivo angular.json
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
      "online_store_angular_2024": {
        "projectType": "application",
        "schematics": {},
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "prefix": "app",
        "architect": {
          "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            "options": {
              "outputPath": "dist/online_store_angular_2024",
              "index": "src/index.html",
              "main": "src/main.ts",
              "polyfills": [
                "zone.js"
              ],
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "src/styles.css",
                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
                "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css",
                "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css",
                "node_modules/swiper/swiper.min.css"
              ],
              "scripts": [
                "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js",
                "src/assets/main.js"                   
              ]
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "budgets": [
                  {
                    "type": "initial",
                    "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                    "maximumError": "1mb"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                    "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                    "maximumError": "4kb"
                  }
                ],
                "outputHashing": "all"
              },
              "development": {
                "buildOptimizer": false,
                "optimization": false,
                "vendorChunk": true,
                "extractLicenses": false,
                "sourceMap": true,
                "namedChunks": true
              }
            },
            "defaultConfiguration": "production"
          },
          "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "browserTarget": "online_store_angular_2024:build:production"
              },
              "development": {
                "browserTarget": "online_store_angular_2024:build:development"
              }
            },
            "defaultConfiguration": "development"
          },
          "extract-i18n": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "online_store_angular_2024:build"
            }
          },
          "test": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
            "options": {
              "polyfills": [
                "zone.js",
                "zone.js/testing"
              ],
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "src/styles.css",
                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
                "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
              ],
              "scripts": [
                "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js",      
                "src/assets/main.js"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './components/product-list/product-list.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProductService } from './services/product.service';

import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SwiperModule
  ],
  providers: [ProductService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

app.component.html
<app-product-list></app-product-list> 

product-list.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/common/product';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[]=[];
  constructor(private productService: ProductService){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listProducts();
  }

  listProducts(){
    this.productService.getProductList().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.products = data;
      }
    )
  }

}

product-list-table.component.html
<!-- Home Section Start -->
<section class="home container" id="home">
  <img src="../../../assets/img/home.png" alt="Home image" />
  <div class="home-text">
    <h1>Cyberpunk<br />2077</h1>
    <a href="" class="btn">Available Now</a>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Home Section End -->

<section class="trending container" id="trending">
  <div class="heading">
    <i class="bx bxs-flame"></i>
    <h2>Juegos en Tendencia</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="trending-content swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!-- Slide 1 -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending1.webp" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>Cyberpunk 2077</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending2.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>Battlefield 2042</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending3.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>Assasin's Creed</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending4.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>Ghost of Tsushima</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending5.png" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>GTA V</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending6.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>Dying Light 2</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending7.png" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>Halo Infinite</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/trending8.png" alt="" />
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2>Resident Evil Village</h2>
            <h3>Accion</h3>
            <div class="rating-download">
              <div class="rating">
                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                <span>4.7</span>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="box-btn"
                ><i class="bx bx-down-arrow-alt"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

Al ejecutar la pagina se ve de la siguiente manera (reduci el tamaño del zoom):

Pero deberia de estar monstrandose de la siguiente manera:

Despues de ver la pagina, se ve que no se esta cargando correctamente los estilos y que la importacion de swiper y main.js no estan bien, pero no logro ver donde esta el error, espero que me puedan ayudar, les comparto el link del repositorio por si quieren probarlo :https://github.com/Fabricio31/AngularStore.git
Mensaje en consola:

Probando Swiper en Html
<swiper-container
  navigation="true"
  pagination="true"
  pagination-clickable="true"
>
  <swiper-slide>
    <img src="../assets/img/new1.jpg">
  </swiper-slide>

  <swiper-slide>
    <img src="../assets/img/new2.jpg">
  </swiper-slide>

  <swiper-slide>
    <img src="../assets/img/new3.jpg">
  </swiper-slide>

</swiper-container>


hola, si sabemos por las capturas que no estan cargando al 100% los estilo o por lo menos el background no lo esta haciendo correctamente ... la pregunta es que has evaluado en la pagina, has revisado la consola de desarrollo del navegador de casualidad???

Errores que veo:

Importación de Swipper, no se porque importas el modulo entero en el componente, en la documentación lo importan diferente: import SwiperCore from 'swiper';
Mucho HTML, usa un *ngFor
Problamente el error sea el conflicto entre los estilos que tiene y lo que parece que es Bootstrap, qué pasa si lo quitas?


@FranciscoNuñezIALover en la consola me aparece un error lo estoy tratando de solucionar, los estilos y js veo que si se estan cargando, he editado la pregunta para que se vea la imagen de la consola

@René, Tienes razon habia un conflicto con el propio estilo css y el de bootstrap, lo elimine de node_modules y ahora si funcionan los estilos completos, con respecto a swiper@9 estoy viendo la documentacion  y el importe es diferente, tambien por lo que veo cambia el codigo en html varia agrego nuevo codigo en la pregunta

pero si ya no hay conflicto de codigo CSS y se ve ... deberia quedar solucionado... agrega una respuest explicando que fue exactamente lo que modificaste a lo mejor a otro le sirva, saludos

@FranciscoNuñezIALover Ok voy a hacer eso gracias a ti y a Rene por responder

Como se dice en el comentario de Rene, la solucion fue eliminar de node_modules bootstrap, que estaba dando conflicto con los estilos propios.

Eliminar Bootstrap a traves de la terminal

npm uninstall bootstrap 


Ir a angular.json y desvincular:

 "styles": 
[
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", (eliminar esta linea)                                            
  "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"  
]


Al ejecutar de nuevo en angular, los estilos propios se ven aplicados en toda la pagina



Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada (aunque tu mismo la hayas respondido).
